# Firefox interacts with my timers somehow ?!?! This is crazy ^^

Tags: c++, firefox, timer

I have a problem with the timers in my win32 C++ DirectX game (a little demo). I am using "timeGetTime" to get the current time and use it to playback the animations or for logic by using the delta time (I also use a constant for normalization when animating). I use a tickrate as low as 2 miliseconds sometimes. I am using only ULONGs when working with time. The game works just fine, but if I start Mozilla Firefox and I start the game after all is playing very fast (the animations and the game logic). It's like fast forwarding. The strange thing is that it seems that a few timers are not affected by this. Does someone have a clue ? What is the connection between Firefox and my timers ? After exiting Firefox is stays the same, but after some undefined time or a PC restart it goes back to normal. Any suggestions are appreciated, even if it is a long shot. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, what version of Firefox is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the default precision of TimeGetTIme is 5ms or more.

This can be altered with the calls timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod functions.
Alterning the precision of TimeGetTime affects all running applications. 
I guess Firefox is calling those functions which affect your application.

Change to use the QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency methods instead which provide high res timing and will not be subject to the issues of TimeGetTime.

EDIT:
A couple of links that show you how to use the functions.

http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/windows/311148/311148/using-queryperformancecounter/

And also note the remarks on the MSDN page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, beware of wrapping counters.

Comment: So this behavior is a bug: "After exiting Firefox is stays the same, but after some undefined time or a PC restart it goes back to normal" ? Like Firefox not calling timeEndPeriod?

Comment: @Matt H Wuhoo Thank you. It makes sense. It's a little late here so I'll fix it tommorow. But can you tell me more about the wrapping counters ? I know what wrapping means, but I don't understand the question.. shouldn't these timers run like 25 days before wrapping ? Care to expand a little ?

Comment: Sounds like it.  The time should be being reset.  But in any case, you don't want other applications to affect your running app.  So that's a bug too.

Comment: +1: Use QueryPerformanceCounter/Frequency for game-related times- the other counters just aren't accurate or precise enough.

Comment: Wrapping just means the counter resets to zero.  It might not be something you need to worry too much about, mainly long running apps would encounter it.

Comment: @user676943; I believe Matt is referring to your counter overflowing and wrapping back to 0.  Since you are using a `ULONG` for your counter it will wrap back to zero after `4,294,967,295` "ticks", which I would be about ~49.7 days if you had a 1ms counter resolution.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes I don't really know.. I guess I could attach a debugger and see for myself, but it's 2 AM and I'm sleepy ^^ I'm also using Firefox 3.6.16 which is older. Also I want to mention that someone running Vista and Firefox 3.6.x didn't exhibit this problem, but other 5 PC's did.. so I don't know right now.

Comment: @Matt H Thanks for the followup and links. And also to the others - cheers for the additional help :D Case closed.