# Firefox interacts with my timers ?! (followup)

Tags: c++, firefox, timer

First please read my older post in which I thought I fixed it. (skip if you don't have time)

[Firefox interacts with my timers somehow ?!?! This is crazy ^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696893/firefox-interacts-with-my-timers-somehow-this-is-crazy)

For those who do not want to read, I'll just sum it up: Firefox messes my timers when it is running so I had to switch from timeGetTime() to QueryPerformanceCounter(), as recommended by the stackoverflow members.. And it is still subjected to the same problem (firefox running makes everything 'fast forwarded'). And I don't understand why now. Maybe I am messing somehow here:

```
ULONG CTimer::time()
{
    __int64 temp;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&temp);
    return (ULONG)(temp*1000/freq);
}
// where freq is the one queried with QueryPerformanceFrequency()
```

Anybody has any idea ? Also any tips are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calculating motion?  If you accurately calculate delta-time (the time since the last tick) with QueryPerformanceCounter, and calculate motion based on that, you should be fine.  So the distance each object moves per tick should be deltatime * speed.

My best guess is you're not doing that, and instead it's based on the framerate, and the framerate changes when you open Firefox (for whatever reason).  Showing your code would be helpful.

One more thing - QueryPerformanceCounter/Frequency may be different for different cores - is your application multithreaded?  If so, opening Firefox may cause Windows shift your application to executing a different core, where QueryPerformanceCounter/Frequency are different.  You must make sure you always call them from the same processor core (set the processor affinity on the thread that calls them).

Comment: @AshleysBrain Nooo.. I'm not doing that :D I get 860 FPS without Firefox and 860 with Firefox, except that when Firefox runs, it messes with the global timer's setting; And I'm not using timeGetTime anymore because of that reason. I still have the problem though. All CPUs from Pentium I onwards have a high res timer (Time Stamp Counter) so it's not like my old Pentium 4 does not have it and it falls back on the regular one. No multithreading. My Pentium 4 is single core and no HT. I repeat, without Firefox ever opened or running, it runs just fine..

Comment: @AshleysBrain I ran out of space.. Continuing: For logic/animations, I use the delta time and a normalizer for fine tuning.

Comment: If you log delta time, is it roughly in the same ballpark with and without Firefox open?  What does the normalizer do and could it be broken?  You really should **post the relevant bits of your code**, it really goes a lot quicker that way.

Comment: @AshleysBrain 

`void Action_attack::ExecAction()
{
 currentTime=Timer.time();
 if(currentTime-lastTick>tickRate) // tickRate currently 2
 {
  // do stuff (taking in account normalizer/normalizers)
  lastTick=currentTime;
 }`

Comment: Stackoverflow's not a forum, edit it in to the original question.  I still don't get what the normalizer is.  Why do you specify a tickRate?  Where's the delta-time calculation?  Why are you truncating the time to milliseconds instead of using a `double`?

Comment: @AshleysBrain
   
   `deltaX=(float)dest->x-pos->x;
   deltaY=(float)dest->y-pos->y;
   distance=sqrtf(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);
   step=((speed->speed)/normalizer)/distance;
   pos->x+=(deltaX*step);
   pos->y+=(deltaY*step);`
   
 Things like that it is used for :D (this is movement logic) the normalizer is just an extra layer for fine tuning, nothing more. I'm not messing anything up, it's that timer who is "counting too fast" for some reason because of Firefox. I don't know why even the high res timer is affected. Can it be possible ?

Comment: @AshleysBrain You are right, I should have posted the code in my original post. tickRate is that delta time, maybe I'm calling it wrong or I don't understand what do you mean by 'delta-time'.. Forget about the normalizer, it isn't relevant and it's not the problem. Yes I saw that the high-res timer needed double, but I didn't change the code yet, I had DWORDs from timeGetTime before. But still, what does this have to do with solving the problem with Firefox ? I appreciate very much that you are trying to help, but understand.. it works fine without Firefox running.

Comment: @AshleysBrain Also closing and opening Firefox makes the game run fine again or breaks it. I just need to understand what Firefox does here, even with the high res timer which the people who answered in my first thread said it won't be affected anymore. And still..

Comment: I... uh... on StackOverflow I don't usually end up being someone's personal support, but: 1) don't have preconceived notions, how do you know it's not the normalizer? (I still don't know what that is) And Firefox is not the problem, your program is. 2) tickRate is not delta time.  I said it's the time since the last tick, which you should measure in seconds as a double, and use to compute the distance to move every tick. 3) I can't read code all on one line!  Edit the original question!  Please!!

Comment: @AshleysBrain Yes, my program is the problem, that's for sure, but why is Firefox affecting it ?I didn't ask you to fix my program/design/implementation flaws.Even if I send it all to you, you still won't be able to fix it because you don't have a clue how is Firefox interacting with it. If you could've answered this, I would have fixed it myself.And I told you that animation/motion isn't frame rate dependent, that's all you need to know (I ran it on different PCs where perf ranged from 60 to 850 FPS and they ran perfect).Stop missing the point every time.Big thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: Firefox is not interacting with your program.  It is probably changing the system load in a particular way that exposes bugs in your program.  I have solved many bugs like this, and it is never "Program X breaks my program", it is "My program is broken and in this case its symptoms only seem to appear when Program X is running".  I am afraid I cannot help you if this does not make sense to you.

Comment: @AshleysBrain Nvm, I deleted my last response. I think I know where the problem is now.  You were right all along, it's my code. Thanks for the help, and sorry for being an a** with you. I should have looked closely..I used the delta time, but not how I should've (a design flaw - using it to determine if I should move, and then do a "step"). It was just me thinking it's the same thing. And it seemed that way, no matter the FPS, but in "special" conditions it seems to fail somehow, not sure yet. Thanks and big hugs to you. Have a nice day and gl with your work, you are good at these things :D

Comment: Ha, well, got there in the end :D Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox itself doesn't mess around with the high performance timers, so the result of such things as setInterval depends on whether something else, such as Google Chrome, does.

Comment: Ok.. Still, it annoys me to no end that I can't find the cause of it and this happens to other Firefox users as well (and not to all of them). Is there a related Win32 API function which can manipulate the high res timer's settings ? Is it even possible ?? I didn't find anything about this on MSDN.